# Unable to view element using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on a web scrapping script that pulls just one value element from CNN.com Fear and Greed Index. After a long time of trying different things I am defeated and cannot seem to understand why on the web developer in chrome I am able to view the element in the HTML script but when I scrape it with python I can't view it or any integer value throughout the page.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://edition.cnn.com/markets/fear-and-greed"
headers = {'User-Agent': '### this is my personal user agent'}

html_content = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
doc = BeautifulSoup(html_content.text, "html.parser")
status = html_content.status_code

fearGreed = doc.find(class_ = "market-fng-gauge__dial-number-value")

print(status)
print(fearGreed)
```

I received a status code of 200 so I believe that the website is recognizing me as a person. The fearGreed variable is able to find the HTML line of code which would hold the value, but the only thing that returns is shown below with no value:

````
<span class="market-fng-gauge__dial-number-value">
</span>```

Thank you in advance to anyone willing to take their time to help me out.
````

Comment: you have javascript there, so dom is created with the class name, but the value is spaces. so this is coming like `<span class="market-fng-gauge__dial-number-value">
 </span>` so need  HTML rendering. can try selenium to build the soup.

Answer (score 1):

You don't see the fear rating because the site use JS for loading the content.

You can just open the network panel and check that you have the request:

```
https://production.dataviz.cnn.io/index/fearandgreed/graphdata
```

The request returns for you the data about that indicator. The code looks like that:

```
import requests
response = requests.get(
'https://production.dataviz.cnn.io/index/fearandgreed/graphdata',
headers = {
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) '
              'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
})
print(response.json()['fear_and_greed']['score'])
```

Whenever you need one parameter only check the network tab first

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, this really helps a lot and it makes a lot of sense. But I am trying to retrace your steps and I can't figure out how you were able to find that link within the network panel. Could you possibly let me know what you did?

Comment: @DanielGonzalez
The Network panel is a developer panel in your Chrome / Firefox browser. You should press F12 and choose "Network" and then open your site. In the panel, you will see the requests/scripts/data that your browser makes when opening the page.